# What could make my VScode terminal give different results than my Gitbash terminal?

Tags: node.js, installation, git-bash

I'm trying to check my Node.js install version and when I type `node -v` in Gitbash I get the version number back, but when I type it in VScode terminal running Gitbash I it says what I ran was not a command.

[image: In Gitbash:]

[image]

I don't know if this matters but all of the relevant programs are installed in the same location (C:\Program Files):
[image: Program files]

Comment: Its a little strange to be in the `c/program files` directory - that makes it seem like you did it there just because that is the only place that works. Do you get the same results in a gitbash terminal when you are just in your home folder, or in the same folder as you are in when you show the vscode directory.

Comment: I checked where my home directory is and it looks like it is program files. I think I may have done this when I was originally trying to get git to work. Do you think I should try to change my home directory or try moving the relevant folder to a different directory? 
  Here is what I got regarding my home directory in Gitbash:                                                                                                        
 `wsm1u@DESKTOP-5ICE6RR MINGW64 ~
$ echo $HOME
/c/Program Files`

Comment: @topsail I forgot to mention in my above comment (to late to edit) but I got the same result in the VScode terminal as in Gitbash with `$ echo $HOME`.

Comment: Program Files is probably not a good place for home, but in general I wanted to know if you get the command not found issue when you are in another folder. So, like `cd /c/Users/<myname> && node -v`. Normally VSCode gitbash terminal behaves the same as the gitbash terminal outside of VSCode. So I guess its weird if both your images above are in fact in the same folder.

Comment: I moved my VScode folder to my desktop, and now I get the npm version number rather than the original error, thank you!